# Probability of a coin falling within a tile

Tags: probability

Consider the following question:
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ1DJ.jpg)

I considered leaving a border of 3 cm on each side of the tile.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwmRX.png)

Now if the center of the coin falls anywhere within this region, the coin stays inside the tile. Otherwise it moves, fully or partly, outside the tile.

So favourable area = 4*4 = 16

Area of sample space = 10*10 = 100

Probability = 16/100 = 0.16

But the correct answer is 0.36

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Possibly an error in the book?

Comment: I agree to your solution.

Comment: Please take the trouble to type the question when reasonably possible, such as in this case.  Images can't be browsed, and links are not always permanent.

Answer (score -1):

*(My previous answer was wrong - we all make mistakes, as suggested in this new response)*

You seem to be correct to be concerned

Your calculation is effectively $\dfrac{(10-2\times 3)^2}{10^2}=\dfrac{4^2}{10^2}=0.16$ and looks sensible

There are two obvious ways to get $0.36 =\dfrac{6^2}{10^2}$, either as $\dfrac{(10-2\times 2)^2}{10^2}$  or as  $\dfrac{(2\times 3)^2}{10^2}$, where the former uses the wrong radius of the coin and the latter fails to subtract from the side of the square.  Both would be wrong, and I would guess that both errors could be possible

Comment: Why radius 1.5 when the coin has radius 3 ?

Comment: Using $r=1.5$ gives the answer $0.49$, which isn't correct

Comment: T.Ford and @ShubhamJohri - Thank you - I have changed my response